# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x156b9090> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, synchronization

I'm currently working with Swift in SpriteKit to make a small/basic mini game, and I'm running into the error displayed in the title above...
Most of the time, everything works fine, but every once in a while, I get this error (the majority of the times it happens, it's right when the game over function *seen below* gets called).  The error always points to the following line:

```
func handle_tilt(acceleration_data: CGFloat)
{
    if ((childNodeWithName("hero")) != nil){
    childNodeWithName("hero")?.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake(acceleration_data * 50, 0))
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?
**the code for the accelerometer set up below is contained in the

```
if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true {
    self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()) {
        (data, error) in
        if (data.acceleration.y != 0) {
            self.motionManager.accelerometerActive == true
            self.handle_tilt(CGFloat(data.acceleration.y))
        }
    }
}
```

The function which, when called, triggers the error...

```
func game_over()
{

    self.removeActionForKey("spawn_flying_squirrels")
    self.removeActionForKey("spawn_flying_squirrels")
    println("Removed the actions")

    self.motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates()
    println("removed motion manager")
    if let recognizers = self.view?.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in recognizers {
            self.view!.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer as! UIGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }

    println("removed the gesture recognizers")

    //saves the score or doesn't (if it doesn't make the high score
    saveScore(score)

    for child in self.children as! [SKNode]
    {
        removeChildrenInArray([child])
    }
    println("removed the children")

    let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    NSLog("HE DEAD")


    view?.presentScene(scene)
}
```

What I think is happening is that the game_over function deletes the "hero" node, and then the handle_tilt function tries unsuccessfully to access "hero" leading to a meltdown. I tried to prevent it with the if statement in the handle_tilt function, but it wasn't a complete success like I had hoped...

Comment: It looks like you are removing items from `self.children` while iterating over its elements.

Comment: Can you show the source to `removeChildrenInArray`?

Comment: You are using fast-enumeration while removing objects from the array. You can use a traditional for loop and remove the objects, or make a copy.

Comment: In what way is it fast enumeration? Can you explain? I thought that what I am doing currently IS just using a traditional for loop...swift is a little new to me

Comment: If you're trying to remove all nodes from `self`, you can replace the loop with `removeAllChildren()`